# Text analysis : What after term-document matrix?

Tags: r, machine-learning, nlp, svm, text-mining

I am trying to build predictive models from text data. I built document-term matrix from the text data (unigram and bigram) and built different types of models on that (like svm, random forest, nearest neighbor etc). All the techniques gave decent results, but I want to improve the results. I tried tuning the models by changing parameters, but that doesn't seem to improve the performance much. What are the possible next steps for me?

Comment: to predict what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a programming question, but anyway:

If your goal is prediction, as opposed to text classification, usual methods are backoff models ([Katz Backoff](http://www.usna.edu/Users/cs/nchamber/courses/nlp/f12/slides/set4-smoothing.pdf)) and interpolation/smoothing, e.g. [Kneser-Ney smoothing](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~wcmac/papers/20050421-smoothing-tutorial.pdf).

More complicated models like Random Forests are AFAIK not absolutely necessary and may pose problems if you need to make predictions quickly. If you are using an interpolation model, you can still tune the model parameters (lambda) using a held out portion of the data.

Finally, I agree with NEO on the reading part and would recommend "Speech and Language Processing" by Jurafsky and Martin.

Comment: Thanks. BTW where can I post these kinds of questions in future?